# Symfony2 Validation against multiple fields

Tags: validation, symfony, entity

I have a contestEntry entity.

It has a number of properties (player Positions) all linking to a fantasyPlayer entity.

On submission of a form i need to check that the different player positions are unique (ie a player has not been put in 2 positions)

Is it possible to use validations for this, as far i can see i can only apply a validation to a property, is there a way to apply validations across the whole entity?

ContestEntry:

```
<?php
namespace FantasyPro\GameBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping AS ORM;
use FantasyPro\DataBundle\Entity\DailyFantasyPlayer;
use FantasyPro\UserBundle\Entity\User;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="FantasyPro\GameBundle\Entity\ContestEntryRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="fp_contestEntry")
 */
class ContestEntry
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", name="id")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean", nullable=true, name="locked")
     */
    private $locked;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="FantasyPro\UserBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="contestEntries")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $user;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="FantasyPro\DataBundle\Entity\DailyFantasyPlayer")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="qb", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $qb;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="FantasyPro\DataBundle\Entity\DailyFantasyPlayer")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="wr1", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $wr1;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="FantasyPro\DataBundle\Entity\DailyFantasyPlayer")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="wr2", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $wr2;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="FantasyPro\DataBundle\Entity\DailyFantasyPlayer")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="rb1", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $rb1;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="FantasyPro\DataBundle\Entity\DailyFantasyPlayer")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="rb2", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $rb2;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="FantasyPro\DataBundle\Entity\DailyFantasyPlayer")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="te", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $te;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="FantasyPro\DataBundle\Entity\DailyFantasyPlayer")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="k", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $k;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="FantasyPro\DataBundle\Entity\DailyFantasyPlayer")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="flex", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $flex;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="FantasyPro\DataBundle\Entity\DailyFantasyPlayer")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="def", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $def;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="FantasyPro\GameBundle\Entity\Contest", inversedBy="contestEntries")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="contest", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $contest;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set locked
     *
     * @param boolean $locked
     *
     * @return ContestEntry
     */
    public function setLocked($locked)
    {
        $this->locked = $locked;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get locked
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function getLocked()
    {
        return $this->locked;
    }

    /**
     * Set user
     *
     * @param \FantasyPro\UserBundle\Entity\User $user
     *
     * @return ContestEntry
     */
    public function setUser(User $user = null)
    {
        $this->user = $user;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get user
     *
     * @return \FantasyPro\UserBundle\Entity\User
     */
    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->user;
    }

    /**
     * Set qb
     *
     * @param \FantasyPro\DataBundle\Entity\DailyFantasyPlayer $qb
     *
     * @return ContestEntry
     */
    public function setQb(DailyFantasyPlayer $qb = null)
    {
        $this->qb = $qb;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get qb
     *
     * @return \FantasyPro\DataBundle\Entity\DailyFantasyPlayer
     */
    public function getQb()
    {
        return $this->qb;
    }

    /**
     * Set wr1
     *
     * @param \FantasyPro\DataBundle\Entity\DailyFantasyPlayer $wr1
     *
     * @return ContestEntry
     */
    public function setWr1(DailyFantasyPlayer $wr1 = null)
    {
        $this->wr1 = $wr1;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get wr1
     *
     * @return \FantasyPro\DataBundle\Entity\DailyFantasyPlayer
     */
    public function getWr1()
    {
        return $this->wr1;
    }

    /**
     * Set wr2
     *
     * @param \FantasyPro\DataBundle\Entity\DailyFantasyPlayer $wr2
     *
     * @return ContestEntry
     */
    public function setWr2(DailyFantasyPlayer $wr2 = null)
    {
        $this->wr2 = $wr2;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get wr2
     *
     * @return \FantasyPro\DataBundle\Entity\DailyFantasyPlayer
     */
    public function getWr2()
    {
        return $this->wr2;
    }

    /**
     * Set rb1
     *
     * @param \FantasyPro\DataBundle\Entity\DailyFantasyPlayer $rb1
     *
     * @return ContestEntry
     */
    public function setRb1(DailyFantasyPlayer $rb1 = null)
    {
        $this->rb1 = $rb1;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get rb1
     *
     * @return \FantasyPro\DataBundle\Entity\DailyFantasyPlayer
     */
    public function getRb1()
    {
        return $this->rb1;
    }

    /**
     * Set rb2
     *
     * @param \FantasyPro\DataBundle\Entity\DailyFantasyPlayer $rb2
     *
     * @return ContestEntry
     */
    public function setRb2(DailyFantasyPlayer $rb2 = null)
    {
        $this->rb2 = $rb2;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get rb2
     *
     * @return \FantasyPro\DataBundle\Entity\DailyFantasyPlayer
     */
    public function getRb2()
    {
        return $this->rb2;
    }

    /**
     * Set te
     *
     * @param \FantasyPro\DataBundle\Entity\DailyFantasyPlayer $te
     *
     * @return ContestEntry
     */
    public function setTe(DailyFantasyPlayer $te = null)
    {
        $this->te = $te;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get te
     *
     * @return \FantasyPro\DataBundle\Entity\DailyFantasyPlayer
     */
    public function getTe()
    {
        return $this->te;
    }

    /**
     * Set k
     *
     * @param \FantasyPro\DataBundle\Entity\DailyFantasyPlayer $k
     *
     * @return ContestEntry
     */
    public function setK(DailyFantasyPlayer $k = null)
    {
        $this->k = $k;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get k
     *
     * @return \FantasyPro\DataBundle\Entity\DailyFantasyPlayer
     */
    public function getK()
    {
        return $this->k;
    }

    /**
     * Set flex
     *
     * @param \FantasyPro\DataBundle\Entity\DailyFantasyPlayer $flex
     *
     * @return ContestEntry
     */
    public function setFlex(DailyFantasyPlayer $flex = null)
    {
        $this->flex = $flex;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get flex
     *
     * @return \FantasyPro\DataBundle\Entity\DailyFantasyPlayer
     */
    public function getFlex()
    {
        return $this->flex;
    }

    /**
     * Set def
     *
     * @param DailyFantasyPlayer $def
     *
     * @return ContestEntry
     */
    public function setDef(DailyFantasyPlayer $def = null)
    {
        $this->def = $def;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get def
     *
     * @return \FantasyPro\DataBundle\Entity\DailyFantasyPlayer
     */
    public function getDef()
    {
        return $this->def;
    }

    /**
     * Set contest
     *
     * @param \FantasyPro\GameBundle\Entity\Contest $contest
     *
     * @return ContestEntry
     */
    public function setContest(Contest $contest = null)
    {
        $this->contest = $contest;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get contest
     *
     * @return \FantasyPro\GameBundle\Entity\Contest
     */
    public function getContest()
    {
        return $this->contest;
    }
}
```

I have a contestHelper class containing various methods, one of them is to check that the selected fantasyPlayers are unique

```
/**
     * Checks to see that the players selected for the squad are unique
     * i.e no player/team has been selected twice
     *
     * @param ContestEntry $contestEntry
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function squadPlayersAreUnique( ContestEntry $contestEntry )
    {
        //checks to see there are no duplicate players in the squad
        $playerArray = array(
            $contestEntry->getWr1()->getPlayer()->getId(),
            $contestEntry->getWr2()->getPlayer()->getId(),
            $contestEntry->getRb1()->getPlayer()->getId(),
            $contestEntry->getRb2()->getPlayer()->getId(),
            $contestEntry->getTe()->getPlayer()->getId(),
            $contestEntry->getK()->getPlayer()->getId(),
            $contestEntry->getFlex()->getPlayer()->getId(),
            $contestEntry->getDef()->getTeam()->getPlayerID()
        );
        return count( $playerArray ) == count( array_unique( $playerArray ) );
    }
```

My controller is very wrong as i have a call to `squadPlayersAreUnique` within my validation controller, and no way to redirect properly back to the page.

Is there a way to add this validation to the entire entity itself?

heres my controller in its current state:

```
/**
     * Shows a form for Updating a contestEntry.
     *
     * @Route("/manageentry/{id}", name="update_contestentry")
     * @Template("GameBundle:ContestEntry:update.html.twig")
     * @param ContestEntry $contestEntry
     * @ParamConverter("contestEntry", class="GameBundle:ContestEntry", options={"id" = "id"})
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse|\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     */
    public function updateEntryAction( ContestEntry $contestEntry = null )
    {
        $session = new Session();
        $session->start();

        // add flash messages

        if ( empty( $contestEntry)) {
            //$session->getFlashBag()->add('error', 'Sorry, We could not find your contest entry!');
            throw $this->createNotFoundException(
                'Sorry, We could not find your contest entry!'
            );
        }
        $request = Request::createFromGlobals();

        $contestHelper = $this->get( 'contest_helper' );

        $contest = $contestEntry->getContest();

        $availablePlayers = $contestHelper->getPlayersforContestResult( $contest );

        $form = $this->createForm( 'contestEntry', $contestEntry );

        $form->handleRequest( $request );

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            //check there are no duplicate players
            if( !$contestHelper->squadPlayersAreUnique( $contestEntry ) ){
                //throw new HttpException(500, 'Duplicate players found in your squad!');
                $session->getFlashBag()->add('error', 'Duplicate players found in your squad, Please check your entry and try again!');
            }

            if( !$contestHelper->entryNotOverBudget( $contestEntry) ){
               // throw new HttpException(500, 'Not Enough funds to draft selected players!');
                $session->getFlashBag()->add('error', 'Not Enough funds to draft selected players, Please check your entry and try again!');
            };

            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist( $contestEntry );
            $em->flush();

            $this->addFlash(
                'success',
                'Contest Entry Updated!!'
            );

            return $this->redirect( $this->generateUrl( 'list_contestentries' ) );
        }

        return array(
            'contestEntry' => $contestEntry,
            'contestForm'  => $form->createView(),
            'contest'      => $contest,
            'playerList'   => $availablePlayers
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add the callback validator on entity level:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Callback.html

Comment: `$context->buildViolation('You have the same player assigned to multiple positions')
                ->atPath('firstName')
                ->addViolation();` can i omit the `->atPath()` as i don't want to relate the validation to a specific field.

Comment: This feels a bit dirty, as i need to do quite a few other types of validation, i.e to check that the players are assigned to their correct positions, among other things, feels like this validation code should live somewhere else rather than the actual entity itself.  as the entity is going to get quite bloated

Comment: Hooking validators to the entity itself has it benefits: you can use them from any context (eg: manual validation) not just from the web forms. But it's always depends on your actual situation.